# How to Distribute OS X application Update which is distributed outside the Mac App Store

Tags: objective-c, macos, updates, sparkle

I would like to know which is the best way to distribute a Mac App's Update to my existing app users.

**App is distribute out side the Mac App Store so can not use the app store to distribute the update**

I would like to do similar to VyprVPN like Download the new version close the app install new version and relaunch the app and this whole thing done without any user interaction.

**I want to do like, Application Installed on my user's Mac now I release new version of my Application then how can I update Application already installed ( Previous Version ) in my user's Mac.**

**Edits**:

I tried to Implement the Sparkle Framework for app update features.

But when i try to update my app I receive the PopUp saying new version of application is available but when I tried to install the new version error occurs saying **UPDATE Error An error occurred while downloading the update. Please try again later.**

Now I could not find reason of this behaviour. Can any one help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pack it into a `.dmg`.  The user mounts the `.dmg` and drags the `.app` to their `Applications` folder.  Job done.

Comment: I am talking about Application Update not Install Fresh version of application

Comment: There is no such thing as Application Update.

Comment: Have you use VyprVPN? I want to do like, Application Installed on my user's MAC now I release new version of my Application then how can I update Application already installed ( Previous Version ) in my user's MAC.

Comment: Great now you have any thoughts regarding this?

Comment: You can't possibly implement this in your current version retroactively. You can build this into the next version, but your users will have to install that version manually.

Comment: Hi, Did you ever find a soultion for this, I am trying to do something similar, can it be done by scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can build the [Sparkle framework](http://sparkle-project.org/) into your app, and then your app can discover and install future updates.